# The class group of the number field $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(X)=X^3-3X^2+X-14$ and let $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$.

I have to find the class gloup of the number field $F$.

**My attempt**

A standard calculation shows that the discriminant of $F$ is given by $\triangle_F=-6043.$ Since $\triangle_F$ is sqauare free we get $O_F=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]\cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(f(X))$. Now the spectrum of $O_F$ is given by $V(f(X))\subset \mathsf{Spec} \: \mathbb {Z}[X]$, therefore the prime ideals of $O_F$ are the those of the type $(p)$, such that $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ is irreducible and $f(X)$ is irreducible $\mathsf{mod} \: p$.

Now, the class group $\mathsf{Cl}(O_F)$ is generated by the prime ideals of $O_F$ such that $N((p))=p^3<M_F$, where $M_F$ is the Minkowski constant associated to $F$, that in this case is given by $$M_F=\dfrac{3!}{3^3}\dfrac{4}{\pi}\sqrt{6043}\approx 21.994996\ldots$$
Since $(2)\subset O_F$ is not prime, because $f(X)=X(X^2-3X+1)$ in $\mathbb{F}_2[X]$ and $N((3))=27>M_F$, we obtain $$\mathsf{Cl}(O_F)=0.$$

Is my attempt correct?

Comment: Why do you say that every prime of $O_F$ comes from a prime in $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: The primes in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ are of the type: $(p)$ with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ irreducible , $(h(X))$ with $h(X)$ irreducible, $(p,h(X))$ with $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ irreducible and $h(X)$ irreducible $\mathsf{mod} \: p$. Therefore the primes in $V(f(X))$ are of the type $(f(X),p)$, such that $f(X)$ is irreducible $\mathsf{mod} \: p$. These ideals correspond to $(p)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, with $f(X)$ irreducible $\mathsf{mod} \: p$.

Comment: Think about $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. Is every prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ of the form $(p)$ for $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ prime?

Comment: A class number cannot equal zero. There is an ideal of norm $2$; is it principal? Likewise there may be ideals of norms $5$, $7$, $11$, $13$, $17$, $19$.

Comment: Yes @ carmichael561, you are right. Where is the mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: You can determine how a prime $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ splits in $O_F$ by determining how $f(X)$ factors mod $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main results that you need are:

1) The Kummer-Dedekind Theorem which, as carmichael561 mentions in the comments, allows you to determine the factorization of a rational prime $p$ in $\mathcal{O}_F$ from the factorization of $f(X)$ mod $p.$

2) The application of Minkowski's theorem which says that "the ideal class group is generated by the classes of the prime ideals of norm less than the Minkowski bound $M_F$".

---

**STEP 1:** Find a small set of generators for $Cl_F.$

In order to find the prime ideals of norm less than $M_F\approx 21.99,$ we can factorize the rational primes 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19 using Kummer-Dedekind. This gives the following prime ideal factorizations:

$2O_F = P_2Q_2$ where $P_2$ has norm 2 and $Q_2$ has norm $2^2$

$3O_F = P_3Q_3$ where $P_3$ has norm 3 and $Q_3$ has norm $3^2$

$5O_F = P_5Q_5$ where $P_5$ has norm 5 and $Q_5$ has norm $5^2$

$7O_F = P_7Q_7$ where $P_7$ has norm 7 and $Q_7$ has norm $7^2$

$11O_F = P_{11}Q_{11}$ where $P_{11}$ has norm 11 and $Q_{11}$ has norm $11^2$

$13O_F = P_{13}Q_{13}$ where $P_{13}$ has norm 13 and $Q_{13}$ has norm $13^2$

$17O_F = P_{17}$ where $P_{17}$ has norm $17^3$

$19O_F = P_{19}Q_{19}$ where $P_{19}$ has norm 19 and $Q_{19}$ has norm $19^2$

It thus follows that the class group $Cl_F$ is generated by the classes of the prime ideals:

$$\{P_2,P_3,P_5,P_7,P_{11},P_{13},P_{19}\}.$$

---

**STEP 2:** Find relations amongst the generators found in STEP 1.

Let $\alpha$ be a root of $f(X).$ We observe that for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$N((\alpha+n)O_F)=|f(-n)|.$$
In particular, we have

$N(\alpha O_F)=14 \Rightarrow \alpha O_F=P_2P_7 \Rightarrow$ we can discard $P_7$ from our generating set.

$N((\alpha+1)O_F)=19 \Rightarrow (\alpha+1) O_F = P_{19} \Rightarrow$ we can discard $P_{19}$ from our generating set.

$N((\alpha-1)O_F)=15 \Rightarrow (\alpha-1) O_F = P_3P_5 \Rightarrow$ we can discard $P_5$ from our generating set.

$N((\alpha-3)O_F)=11 \Rightarrow (\alpha-3) O_F = P_{11} \Rightarrow$ we can discard $P_{11}$ from our generating set.

$N((\alpha+4)O_F)=130 \Rightarrow (\alpha+4) O_F = P_2P_5P_{13} \Rightarrow$  we can discard $P_{13}$ from our generating set.

$N((\alpha-4)O_F)=6 \Rightarrow (\alpha-1) O_F = P_2P_3 \Rightarrow$ we can discard $P_3$ from our generating set.

It therefore follows that $Cl_F$ is cyclic generated and that the class of $P_2$ is a generator.

It remains to compute the order of the class of $P_2$ in $Cl_F.$

Observe that $N((\alpha-2)O_F)=16.$

The Kummer-Dedekind theorem tells us that 
$$Q_2=(2,\alpha^2+\alpha+1)O_F$$
and so we see that $Q_2$ doesn't divide $(\alpha-2)O_F.$

[Proof: $\alpha-2 \in Q_2 \Rightarrow \alpha=(\alpha-2)+2 \in Q_2 \Rightarrow1=(\alpha^2+\alpha+1)-(\alpha+1)\alpha \in Q_2,$ contradiction.]

Hence we must have $(\alpha-2)O_F=P_2^4$ and so the order of the class of $P_2$ is either 1, 2 or 4.

We now show that neither $P_2$ nor $P_2^2$ is principal...

Comment: I thank you for your solution. However the group $Cl_F$ is not trivial. It is generated by an element, for example $\mathfrak{p}_2$, subjected to the relation $\mathfrak{p}_2^4\sim 1$ (take the ideal $(\alpha-7)=\mathfrak{p}_3^3\mathfrak{p}_7$). Now I need to show that this group is $\mathbb{Z}_4$, how you can se, for example, by using SageMath. In order to do this I have to find a unit in $O_F$. Have you suggestions to do this?

Comment: You're absolutely right! Did you see where I went wrong? Sorry about that. I have amended my answer accordingly. I'm still trying to think of an elementary way to show that neither $P_2$ nor $P_2^2$ is principal :)